# disable some calls in default function

Tags: k6

```
export default function() {
http.get(api_1);
http.get(api_2);
http.get(api_3);
};
```

I want to disable the request for api_2.I want to do this by passing some parameters during the k6 script execution.Is k6 provide some support for this?

I tried using the boolean flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use environment variables to control the k6 script execution: https://docs.k6.io/docs/environment-variables

So, in your case you can run write your function like this:

```
export default function() {
  http.get(api_1);
  if (__ENV.SOMETHING) {
    http.get(api_2);
  }
  http.get(api_3);
};
```

And then execute `k6 run script.js` when you don't want to execute the second API call and `k6 run --env SOMETHING=true script.js` when you do.

Comment: Can i use file to import this variable..For example import envVariables.js in script.js file

Comment: Sure, here's an example: https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/issues/1101#issuecomment-518172431